# What is the meaning of signs and numbers appearing in scoring system of AAAI?

Tags: conference, peer-review

I've received the reviewer reports for a paper I submitted to AAAI (the [Association for the Advancement of Artificial Intelligence](http://www.aaai.org/home.html)).
I found their scoring method a bit confusing and I would like some help understanding their review of my work.

Each aspect is followed by a number and some plus and minus signs. For instance:

> 8(+++)

Can any experienced reviewers/authors explain the meaning of these signs and the range of scores?

Comment: Clarified slightly, including focus on AAAI (EasyChair allows many ranking systems)

Comment: So each reviewer gave a score and couple of signs for each aspect? I would guess 8(+++) means three reviewers evaluate this aspect to 8

Answer (score 2):

I dug up my AAAI reviews from two years ago, and it looks like they've been tinkering with their scoring system, so I can't tell you a precise answer.  I can give the general principle, however:

EasyChair allows the chairs of a conference to configure a set of "attributes" for scoring.  Each attribute gets both a numerical value and a descriptor.  Some examples from AAAI two years ago:

Individual attributes:

> 5: (ground-breaking (top 15%), a sufficient basis for accepting the paper)
>
> 4: (positive, a factor in accepting the paper)
>
> 2: (problematic, a factor in rejecting the paper)

Overall ratings:

> 2: (Strong acceptance.  A 5 or 6 in some category, no 1 in any category.)
>
> -2: (Strong rejection.  A 1 in some category, no 5 or 6 in any category.)

So as you can see, then they were using a 1-6 scale and a -2 to 2 scale.

From the sample you gave, my guess is that they're currently using a 1-10 scale, with 5 being neutral.  Thus

> 8 (+++)

Would translate approximately to "8 out of 10 (a very good score, three positive steps above neutral)."

Comment: This is outdated. For AAAI'24 the scores are new: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/203574/119679