# What are the different acceptance scores for AAAI'24?

Tags: peer-review

What are the different options of the reviewers for "OVERALL EVALUATION" for the 38th Annual AAAI Conference on Artificial Intelligence (Association for the Advancement of Artificial)?

I think the answer https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/49478/119679

- Strong Accept (+3)
- Accept (+2)
- Weak Accept (+1)
- Borderline (0)
- Weak Reject (-1)
- Reject (-2)
- Strong Reject (-3)

to [What are the different acceptance levels in peer review?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/49476/119679) is not valid anymore? Also [What is the meaning of signs and numbers appearing in scoring system of AAAI?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/30432/what-is-the-meaning-of-signs-and-numbers-appearing-in-scoring-system-of-aaai) is outdated.

Last year there was also the new option "borderline accept" (https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/qlt4cz/d_aaai_2022_paper_reviews/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The options at AAAI'24 are:

- **Strong Accept**: Technically flawless paper with groundbreaking impact on at least one area of AI or excellent impact on multiple areas of AI, with flawless quality, reproducibility, resources, and no unaddressed ethical considerations.
- **Accept**: Technically solid paper, with high impact on at least one sub-area of AI or modest-to-high impact on more than one area of AI, with good to excellent quality, reproducibility, and if applicable, resources, and no unaddressed ethical considerations.
- **Weak accept**: Technically solid paper where reasons to accept, e.g., good novelty, outweigh reasons to reject, e.g., fair quality.
- **Weak Reject**: Technically solid paper where reasons to reject, e.g., poor novelty, outweigh reasons to accept, e.g. good quality.
- **Reject**: For instance, a paper with poor quality, limited impact, poor reproducibility, mostly unaddressed ethical considerations.
- **Strong Reject**: For instance, a paper with trivial results, limited novelty, poor impact, or unaddressed ethical considerations.